# Why do I get /emitKeypressEvents error while installing React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

I am currently using Flutter, so iOS and Android simulators are installed. When I start a React Native project using IntelliJ, the following error occurs. What is the reason?

```
├─ y18n@5.0.8
├─ yallist@4.0.0
├─ yaml@2.3.1
├─ yargs-parser@21.1.1
└─ yocto-queue@0.1.0
✨  Done in 12.21s.
node:internal/readline/emitKeypressEvents:74
            throw err;
            ^

TypeError: cli.init is not a function
    at run (/Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:302:7)
    at createProject (/Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at /Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:217:7
    at /Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:316:32
    at /Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:142:25
    at assembler (/Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:313:9)
    at /Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:322:32
    at /Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:597:5
    at Interface.onLine (/Users/choiyunseok/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/read/lib/read.js:111:5)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:514:28)

Node.js v20.5.1
Done
```

I don't know what the error is. How to solve this situation?

react-native doctor --

```
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: Not Found
 ✖ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ Ruby
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
 ✓ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment
```

flutter doctor --

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale ko-KR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

What's the matter?

If you create a project with npx react-native init and access it with intellij, iPhone runs but Android does not.

Comment: Have you used React Native doctor?

Comment: Fixed problem, added react-native doctor above

Comment: Try to install [`Android Studio`](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=Cj0KCQjw0IGnBhDUARIsAMwFDLm-CcZShv-zp0SljIXWw3xy3p7qznjR_WTh0QzQ5PpsKkD5V6TQTy4aAt0gEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) and all of your Android problems will be fixed automatically.

Comment: Your `ADB`, `ADNROID_SDK` and `ANDROID_HOME` are not installed or set up. by installing Android Studio all of them will be fixed. I doubt how you were able to run Flutter though.